# Merging ACCESS projects (transferring a switchboard)

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, merge

I am enhancing and fixing the forms/queries/VBcode etc. for an access 2007 database.  The current version is being actively used and when I am done with my changes I need to transfer in my changes without disrupting the data stored in the tables already in the running mdb.

I'm not entirely sure how to handle the "merge" when the time comes.  As an experiment I have a local backup copy of the version I started working on and used the import external Access data option.  This imported the new forms, queries, vb, etc.  But the only hang up is that the switchboard form isn't the new.  Switchboard forms of course are guided by the switchboard manager but I was hoping that all that logic is held inside the form itself somehow.  It seems this is not the case.  After the import there is a new form of the same name with a number after it as expected, and the correct create/modify date.  But when open it looks exactly the same as the old switchboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access switchboard manager uses a table named *Switchboard Items* to dynamically populate switchboard form pages.  You will need to transfer the updated version of that table to make your revised switchboard pages available in the other project.

Comment: Yep actually just noticed that while fiddling around.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me as if you have both the data and the forms etc in the one database. This is not a good idea at all and if you are updating, it is the ideal time to correct the problem. If you split the database, any updates to forms and code can be simply copied to the user without worrying about the data. You will find some notes here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx

Comment: Thanks, certainly will make updates in the future.  The system was originally created by someone who simply had some access and VBS experience, not an expert or developer.  I'm trying to clean up some of the mess but it's at the point of needing a re-write and there sadly isn't enough time.