# Removing Linked Tables in Access, Need to Merge Database After

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, merge

So I have tried doing some reading around and the closest I've come to an answer is [Merging ACCESS projects (transferring a switchboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712400/merging-access-projects-transferring-a-switchboard).  I two .mdb files, one back-end that has data and one front-end that has forms, queries, and reports.  I have a user who has been holding the SHIFT key to open up the linked tables on the front end and modify data.

What I've decided to do to counter this is create DAO connections in VBA to remove the linked tables.  Then I'll create a .mde file to hide the VBA.  Is that a smart move?

And with that I'll be creating a copy of the current database, modifying the front-end and back-end, and going live with it next week.  What is the easiest way to bring in the newest data from the time I copy the database to the time I go live?  I need all my new data, so do I just rename the old database to the new one and relocate it?  Or do I copy and paste each table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you implemented something which prevents the user from opening the back-end db file directly in Access?

Comment: I need to experiment, but I'm wondering if I can just modify permissions?  Or if that will interfere with the DAO connection then I'll password protect it and manually enter the password in the DAO connection.  Then the .mde file will not show the VBA for the connection.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by this question.  If the point is you want a new back-end db file which contains the latest updates to the data in the original, copy the original db file to the new name.  Just make sure no-one is using the original when you copy (no `.ldb` lock file present).  Set the database password on the copy afterward.  Is that satisfactory?

Comment: Copying with a password attached and renaming is the answer I was looking for.  I just don't want a user to be able to modify the front end linked tables either when they hold SHIFT and open it.  Hence why I want to create a DAO connection too.  Am I over complicating it?

Comment: My impression is yours is a use case for which Access is not well suited.  My preferred alternative would be to move the data to a client-server db.  If that is not an option, consider ULS (user-level security) for your MDB file.  Revoke view and edit privileges from the tables.  Grant those permissions to the db objects you want the user to use when interacting with the data.  But ULS is complicated to set up and is not strong security.  So this isn't a great option, either.

Comment: That is extremely useful information.  I do have a shared server where I keep the backend db and users keep a copy of the front end on their desktop.  A copy script is triggered if the newest version is not on the desktop.  I appreciate your input @HansUp and I will look into ULS further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to edit your database to no longer allow the **SHIFT** key to function the way your user expects.  Have a look at this Microsoft document on the [AllowBypassKey functionality](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-HA010341516.aspx) and how to turn it off.

You can also make it an MDE file (or ACCDE of you're using 2K7 or 2K10) so your user can't get into the front end in design mode, thus eliminating their capability to weasel into the back end.

Or have them fired for policy violations.  :o)

Comment: Between adding a password to the back-end and doing like you said with disabling the SHIFT key http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826765 here this turned out great.  Thanks!